# iframe form resets after submiting and succeeds only on second try

Tags: html

I'm trying to put on a single page 3 external iframes[credit card information] as follows:

```html
<div class="row">
  <h5>First guy</h5>
  <iframe src="https://www.foo.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h5>Second guy</h5>
  <iframe src="https://www.foo.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h5>Third guy</h5>
  <iframe src="https://www.foo.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

The first iframe is doing its job but when i move to the second one, after I enter the information and click submit, it resets and I have to put the information again, after I do it, it succeeds.

any thoughts?

B.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with cookies, or some temporary data included in the html/js of the frame content.

Imagine all 3 iframes think "I have a cookie indicating the next transaction is #5"

You submit the order in the first one. The server now stores #6 as the next transaction.

When you submit in the second iframe, you send along #5. The server sees it and thinks "something's wrong, let's make them retry"
So your second iframe reloads, and this time gets the appropriate cookie.
That's why it works after a reload.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to fix that problem?

Comment: @Ben you'd have to refresh the iframes yourself in code before the user tries to input information. Personally I would only display one iframe at a time. Creating them as needed.